# How to see if player answers the value that corresponds to the key of that value

Tags: python, dictionary, random

Write a simple quiz game that has a list of ten questions and a list of answers to those questions. The game should give the player four randomly selected questions to answer. It should
ask the questions one-by-one, and tell the player whether they got the question right or
wrong. At the end it should print out how many out of four they got right.

I've created one function that chooses one random key from my dictionary. My dictionary consists of 10 keys ('What is the capital of 'a' country) and each key has one answer (the capital of that country 'a'). Imagine i have (for now the 3 following functions).

```
import random

questions = {'What is the capital of Portugal':'Lisbon','What is the capital of France':'Paris','What is the capital of Germany':'Berlin','What is the capital of Netherlands':'Amsterdam','What is the capital of Belgium':'Brussels','What is the capital of Nepal':'Kathmandu','What is the capital of Spain':'Madrid','What is the capital of England':'London','What is the capital of Ireland':'Dublin','What is the capital of United_States':'Washington'} #dictionary with all questions and answers

#function that returns random question from dict
def questions_sorting():

  return random.sample(list(questions.keys()),1)

print(questions_sorting())


#function that asks player for capital input
def player_answer():

  return input('Digit your final answer - \n')

def countries_game():

  right_ans = 0 #counts the number of right answers 
  wrong_ans = 0 #counts the number of wrong answers
  num_questions = 0 #counts the number of questions displayed so far

  while num_questions < 4: #there will be four questions to be displayed
    cpu_question = questions_sorting()
    player_choice = player_answer()
    num_questions += 1
```

How can i see if a player enters the correct value for the the asked key?.
Also in my question sort function i am sorting one question . How can i ask another question without the possibility of asking the same question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also just do:

```
import random

questions = {'What is the capital of Portugal':'Lisbon','What is the capital of France':'Paris','What is the capital of Germany':'Berlin','What is the capital of Netherlands':'Amsterdam','What is the capital of Belgium':'Brussels','What is the capital of Nepal':'Kathmandu','What is the capital of Spain':'Madrid','What is the capital of England':'London','What is the capital of Ireland':'Dublin','What is the capital of United_States':'Washington'} #dictionary with all questions and answers

count_false = 0
count_true = 0
q = random.sample(list(questions.keys()),4)

for item in q:
    answ = input(item)
    if answ == questions[item]:
        count_true += 1
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        count_false += 1
        print("Incorrect! The correct answer is ", questions[item])

print ("You have {} correct answers and {} incorrect answers".format(count_true,count_false))
```

output:

```
What is the capital of Nepal Berlin
Incorrect! The correct answer is  Kathmandu
What is the capital of Netherlands Berlin
Incorrect! The correct answer is  Amsterdam
What is the capital of Ireland Dublin
Correct!
What is the capital of France Paris
Correct!
You have 2 correct answers and 2 incorrect answers
```

NOTE:

> **random.sample() function**
>
> `sample()` is an inbuilt function of random module in Python that
>   returns a particular length list of items chosen from the sequence
>   i.e. list, tuple, string or set. Used for random sampling without
>   replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `player_choice` is the answer by comparing it to the answer obtained from providing question as key. Then, delete the question so that you don't ask the same question.

```
import random

#function that returns random question from dict
def questions_sorting(questions):
    # [0] because you don't want to ask a question with a list
    return random.sample(list(questions.keys()),1)[0] 

#function that asks player for capital input
def player_answer():
    return input('Digit your final answer - \n')

def countries_game():
    questions = {'What is the capital of Portugal': 'Lisbon', 'What is the capital of France': 'Paris',
                 'What is the capital of Germany': 'Berlin', 'What is the capital of Netherlands': 'Amsterdam',
                 'What is the capital of Belgium': 'Brussels', 'What is the capital of Nepal': 'Kathmandu',
                 'What is the capital of Spain': 'Madrid', 'What is the capital of England': 'London',
                 'What is the capital of Ireland': 'Dublin',
                 'What is the capital of United_States': 'Washington'}  # dictionary with all questions and answers
    right_ans = 0 #counts the number of right answers
    wrong_ans = 0 #counts the number of wrong answers
    num_questions = 0 #counts the number of questions displayed so far
    while num_questions < 4: #there will be four questions to be displayed
        cpu_question = questions_sorting(questions)
        print(cpu_question)
        player_choice = player_answer()
        if player_choice==questions[cpu_question]:
            print('correct')
            right_ans+=1
        else:
            print('incorrect')
            wrong_ans+=1
        num_questions += 1
        del questions[cpu_question]
    print(f'correct: {right_ans}, incorrect: {wrong_ans}')
countries_game()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like:

```
import random
questions = {'What is the capital of Portugal':'Lisbon','What is the capital of France':'Paris','What is the capital of Germany':'Berlin','What is the capital of Netherlands':'Amsterdam','What is the capital of Belgium':'Brussels','What is the capital of Nepal':'Kathmandu','What is the capital of Spain':'Madrid','What is the capital of England':'London','What is the capital of Ireland':'Dublin','What is the capital of United_States':'Washington'} #dictionary with all questions and answers
num_questions, right_ans, wrong_ans = 0, 0, 0
while num_questions < 4:
    q = random.choice(list(questions.keys()))
    a = input(q + " ?\n")
    if a.lower().strip() == questions[q].lower():
        print("correct!"); right_ans +=1;
    else:
        print("Incorrect! The correct answer is", questions[q]);  wrong_ans+=1
    del questions[q]; num_questions +=1

print("\nRight Answers:", right_ans, "Wrong Answers:", wrong_ans)
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/6e585cddf9)